# Is there a standard way to describe SSO token extraction from an HTTP request?

Tags: java, pattern-matching, httprequest, single-sign-on

I'm working on building a pluggable SSO architecture for web servers, where we could be using any SSO technology.  This means I need to find the SSO token using headers, cookies, parameters, and/or resourceURI.

So I need to teach my web server where to look for the SSO token to perform authentication, in a declarative manner ideally.

My proposal: an XML format to describe where to locate the SSO token:

```
<!-- from an arbitrary cookie -->    <!-- from an arbitrary header -->
<token>                              <token>
   <location>cookie</location>           <location>header</location>
   <name>cookieName</name>               <name>headerName</name>
</token>                             </token>
```

We can do the same thinkg for parameters, and for path elements we can specify "first", "last" or by position which path element to choose, or use regular expressions to match the path.

So is there a standard way of "matching" elements of a full HttpRequest to extract a string?